# Send JAX-RS JsonArray response custom http header

Tags: jax-rs

Look at this very basic Java code: It is a very simple REST webservice which returns JSON data:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public JsonArray test()
{
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonReader = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    jsonReader.add(...);
    jsonReader.add(...);

    return  (JsonArray) jsonReader.build();
}
```

It works fine, but i want to send a specific http header in response. But i cannot do it because the return type is JsonArray. How can i send this header ?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17883255/8294374

Comment: In regards to the duplicate link, if you don't want to change the method parameter, you can also inject the HttpServletRequest as a class field.